# Baby Rudin Theorem 7.18

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, derivatives

Here is Theorem 7.18 from Baby Rudin:

> There exists a real continuous function on the real line which is nowhere differentiable.

Here is a proof of the theorem:

> Define
> $$\tag{34} \varphi(x) = \lvert x \rvert \qquad \qquad (-1 \leq x \leq 1) $$
> and extend the definition of $\varphi(x)$ to all real $x$ by requiring that
> $$ \tag{35} \varphi(x+2) = \varphi(x). $$
> Then, for all $s$ and $t$,
> $$\tag{36}  \lvert \varphi(s) - \varphi(t) \rvert \leq \lvert s-t \rvert. $$
> In particular, $\varphi$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^1$. Define
> $$ \tag{37} f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n \varphi \left( 4^n x \right). $$
> Since $0 \leq \varphi \leq 1$, Theorem 7.10 shows that the series (37) converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}^1$. By Theorem 7.12, $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^1$.
> Now fix a real number $x$ and a positive integer $m$. Put
> $$ \tag{38} \delta_m = \pm \frac{1}{2} \cdot 4^{-m} $$
> where the sign is so chosen that no integer lies between $4^m x$ and $4^m \left( x + \delta_m \right)$. This can be done, since $4^m \left\lvert \delta_m \right\rvert = \frac{1}{2}$. Define
> $$ \tag{39} \gamma_n = \frac{ \varphi \left( 4^n \left( x + \delta_m \right)  \right) - \varphi \left( 4^n x \right)  }{ \delta_m }. $$
> When $n > m$, then $4^n \delta_m$ is an even integer, so that $\gamma_n = 0$. When $0 \leq n \leq m$, (36) implies that $\left\lvert \gamma_n \right\rvert \leq 4^n$.
> Since $\left\lvert \gamma_m \right\rvert = 4^m$, we conclude that
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \left\lvert \frac{ f \left( x + \delta_m \right) - f(x)  }{ \delta_m  }  \right\rvert &= \left\lvert \sum_{n=0}^m \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n \gamma_n  \right\rvert \\ 
> &\geq 3^m - \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} 3^n \\
> &= \frac{1}{2} \left( 3^m + 1 \right).
> \end{align}
> $$
> As $m \to \infty$, $\gamma_m \to 0$. It follows that $f$ is not differentiable at $x$.

I have two questions regarding the proof.

1. At $(38)$ it's stated that the sign is so chosen that no integer lies between $4^m x$ and $4^m \left( x + \delta_m \right)$. Why is it necessary that no integer should be within that range and what would happen if they were?
2. At the later part of the proof we have:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \left\lvert \frac{ f \left( x + \delta_m \right) - f(x)  }{ \delta_m  }  \right\rvert &= \left\lvert \sum_{n=0}^m \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n \gamma_n  \right\rvert \\ 
   &\geq 3^m - \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} 3^n \\
   &= \frac{1}{2} \left( 3^m + 1 \right).
   \end{align}
   $$
   I want to know why is the following part true:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \left\lvert \sum_{n=0}^m \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n \gamma_n  \right\rvert 
   &\geq 3^m - \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} 3^n \\
   \end{align}
   $$

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If you look at a picture of $\varphi$, it is a saw blade with a slope of $1$ in intervals of the form $(2k,2k+1)$, and a slope of $-1$ in intervals of the form $(2k+1,2(k+1))$. The approach to the proof is essentially to take an arbitrary $x$ and show that there exists a sequence $\{\delta_m\}$ such that $\delta_m \to 0$, but
   $$
   \left|\frac{f(x+\delta_m)-f(x)}{\delta_m}\right| \to +\infty.
   $$
   This method sufficiently demonstrates that the difference quotient cannot converge. The reason we guarantee that no integer lies between $4^mx$ and $4^m(x+\delta_m)$ is to guarantee that we are comparing points on the "saw blade" that correspond to the same branch (either one with slope of $1$ or $-1$, but no mixing). There's no reason to not do this because $\delta_m \to 0$ anyways, and it makes the proof easier.
2. Here's the full work for that step. The first step of reducing the sum from an infinite sum to one up to $m$ is because $\gamma_n=0$ for $n>m$. Later, we use that $\gamma_m=4^m$.
   \begin{align}
   \left\lvert \frac{ f \left( x + \delta_m \right) - f(x)  }{ \delta_m  }  \right\rvert &= \left\lvert \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n \gamma_n  \right\rvert \\
   &= \left\lvert \sum_{n=0}^m \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n \gamma_n  \right\rvert \\
   &= \left\lvert \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^m \gamma_m+ \sum_{n=0}^{m-1}\left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n \gamma_n  \right\rvert \\
   &\geq \left\lvert \left(\frac{3}{4}\right) ^m \gamma_m \right\rvert-\left\lvert \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n \gamma_n\right\rvert  \\
   &= 3^m -\left\lvert \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n \gamma_n\right\rvert  \\
   &\geq 3^m - \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n |\gamma_n|  \\
   &\stackrel{|\gamma_n|\leq 4^n}{\geq} 3^m - \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} 3^n \\
   &= \frac{1}{2} \left( 3^m + 1 \right).
   \end{align}

Comment: How did you get the last equality?