# What is the graph of Rudin's 7.18 function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, graphing-functions

Code borrowed from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4215030/baby-rudin-theorem-7-18)

Theorem 7.18 from Baby Rudin:

> There exists a real continuous function on the real line which is nowhere differentiable.

proof

> Define
> $$\tag{34} \varphi(x) = \lvert x \rvert \qquad \qquad (-1 \leq x \leq 1) $$
> and extend the definition of $\varphi(x)$ to all real $x$ by requiring that
> $$ \tag{35} \varphi(x+2) = \varphi(x). $$
> Then, for all $s$ and $t$,
> $$\tag{36}  \lvert \varphi(s) - \varphi(t) \rvert \leq \lvert s-t \rvert. $$
> In particular, $\varphi$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^1$. Define
> $$ \tag{37} f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n \varphi \left( 4^n x \right). $$
> Since $0 \leq \varphi \leq 1$, Theorem 7.10 shows that the series (37) converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}^1$. By Theorem 7.12, $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^1$.
> Now fix a real number $x$ and a positive integer $m$. Put
> $$ \tag{38} \delta_m = \pm \frac{1}{2} \cdot 4^{-m} $$
> where the sign is so chosen that no integer lies between $4^m x$ and $4^m \left( x + \delta_m \right)$. This can be done, since $4^m \left\lvert \delta_m \right\rvert = \frac{1}{2}$. Define
> $$ \tag{39} \gamma_n = \frac{ \varphi \left( 4^n \left( x + \delta_m \right)  \right) - \varphi \left( 4^n x \right)  }{ \delta_m }. $$
> When $n > m$, then $4^n \delta_m$ is an even integer, so that $\gamma_n = 0$. When $0 \leq n \leq m$, (36) implies that $\left\lvert \gamma_n \right\rvert \leq 4^n$.
> Since $\left\lvert \gamma_m \right\rvert = 4^m$, we conclude that
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \left\lvert \frac{ f \left( x + \delta_m \right) - f(x)  }{ \delta_m  }  \right\rvert &= \left\lvert \sum_{n=0}^m \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n \gamma_n  \right\rvert \\ 
> &\geq 3^m - \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} 3^n \\
> &= \frac{1}{2} \left( 3^m + 1 \right).
> \end{align}
> $$
> As $m \to \infty$, $\gamma_m \to 0$. It follows that $f$ is not differentiable at $x$.

I want to see the graph of $f(x)$ I don't have the tools that graph such functions

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rlknnhil1g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the function after summing the first 25 terms in the series.

[image: This is the function after summing the first 25 terms in the series.]

And this is the function as we sum from 1 to 15 terms.

[image: And this is the function as we sum from 1 to 15 terms.]

Here is the code to generate it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def phi(x):
    return np.abs(x % 2 - 1)

def f(x, num_terms=25):
    n = np.arange(num_terms)[:, np.newaxis]
    terms = (3/4)**n * phi(4**n * x)
    return np.sum(terms, axis=0)

# Generate x values
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100000)

# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

# Initialize the plot
line, = ax.plot([], [])

# Set up the plot properties
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(0, 5)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('f(x)')
ax.grid(True)

# Update function for the animation
def update(i):
    y = f(x, i+1)
    line.set_data(x, y)
    ax.set_title(f'Visualization of f(x) with {i+1} terms')
    return line,

# Create the animation
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=15, interval=500, blit=True)

# Save the animation as a GIF
anim.save('f(x)_animation.gif', writer='pillow')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Wow, what program did you used ?

Comment: Just python with numpy and matplotlib. By the way, you can click the check mark next to an answer to mark the answer as accepted, if the answer sufficiently answers your question.

Comment: I want to learn python (for mathematical stuff )  where can I begin ?

Comment: I think it is outdated by now, but I learned from this set of notes: https://belglas.files.wordpress.com/2018/03/cpwp.pdf

Comment: do I need any previous knowledge to read this ? as you can see I know nothing about programming

Comment: This + chatgpt should be enough, I imagine.